# Iterate object tree with arrays and objects to clean out null/undefined or empty string using node.js

Tags: node.js

So, I've found a ton of good suggestions on how to iterate over an object "tree" and filter out `null`, `undefined`, etc. which all works fine for objects and attributes.

I am trying to clean a object tree that has a ton of arrays:

```json
"cac:Delivery": [
  {
    "cac:DeliveryLocation": [
      {
        "cbc:Name": [
          {
            "_": "Company Name"
          }
        ],
        "cac:Address": [
          {
            "cbc:StreetName": [
              {
                "_": "The Street 123"
              }
            ],
            "cbc:AdditionalStreetName": [
              {
                "_": null
              }
            ],
            "cbc:CityName": [
              {
                "_": "The City"
              }
            ],
            "cbc:PostalZone": [
              {
                "_": ""
              }
            ],
            "cac:Country": [
              {
                "cbc:IdentificationCode": [
                  {
                    "_": ""
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The above sample is a snippet of the full message and why it looks like this is because the original is a `UBL XML` message that we run `xml2js` on to transform it from XML to JSON.

We then need to run some other mappings and extraction of values on the tree. The next step of the flow won't accept any `null`, `undefined` or `empty string` as values.

The problem I have a that I can't figure out any nifty way of traversing the tree with the arrays and clean out the tree (=remove the "empty" attributes).

In the sample, cleaning out `cbc:IdentificationCode` will then of course make `cac:Country` to be empty in turn...

There are hundreds of "groups" that I need to "clean" so I need to come up with something dynamic and it is also important that the order of attributes are kept...

The above should result in:

```json
"cac:Delivery": [
  {
    "cac:DeliveryLocation": [
      {
        "cbc:Name": [
          {
            "_": "Company Name"
          }
        ],
        "cac:Address": [
          {
            "cbc:StreetName": [
              {
                "_": "The Street 123"
              }
            ],
            "cbc:CityName": [
              {
                "_": "The City"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**EDIT**:
The data is based upon UBL JSON representation: https://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/UBL-2.1-JSON/v2.0/cnd01/UBL-2.1-JSON-v2.0-cnd01.html

Various samples can be found here: https://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/UBL-2.1-JSON/v2.0/cnd01/json/
(I am currently working on the "Invoice" message)

**EDIT2**:
Figured to share to "iterator" I came up with that is traversing the entire tree and handles each Object/Array/Attribute:

```js
function iterate(obj) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log('KEY:', key);
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
      console.log('ARRAY');
      obj[key].forEach((k) => iterate(k));
    } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      console.log('OBJECT');
      if (obj[key]) {
        iterate(obj[key]);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Key / Value:', key, value);
      if (!value) {
        console.log('THIS IS AN EMPTY VALUE!');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: is the schema fixed? As in there are a lot of arrays with only 1 object, will that change?

Comment: I have to understand does the value have array as key with object in it like : `{ "_": "The City"}` ? It is fixed or dynamic? My question is every key might be dynamic, but does it values follow the same pattern?

Comment: The schema is fixed, yes... Edited original question with links to the standard, @Rinkesh P. There might be key as `$` as well, apart from `_`, @Apoorva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, maybe not the most elegant of solutions but after a few hours of pondering this I solved it using `lodash` `_.set()` which can create a object tree from paths... I called my function `deepClean()` and this now returns an object without any `nullish` values (but I do want to keep `0`'s):

```js
function iterate(obj, arrObj, path = '') {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    // Construct the path to the object/array that we are currently looking at
    const newPath = `${path}${path ? '.' : ''}['${key}']`;
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
      // If it is an array we have to add the [index] to the path as well, then iterate over the array
      obj[key].forEach((k, index) => iterate(k, arrObj, `${newPath}[${index}]`));
    } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      // If it's an object, and the object has any child/value iterate again
      if (obj[key]) {
        iterate(obj[key], arrObj, newPath);
      }
    } else {
      // If this is a "value" push it to the Array
      arrObj.push([`${path}.${key}`, value]);
    }
  });
}

const deepClean = (obj) => {
  // We need to clean the whole object tree and remove any array/object/key that are "nullish"
  // however, we must keep values as zero (number) as e.g. VAT can be zero
  const arrObj = [];
  const newObj = {};
  // Call itarate() to loop through the entire tree recursivly and build an array as [path-to-object, value]
  iterate(obj, arrObj);
  arrObj.forEach((o) => {
    // Start creating the new cleaned object from the values/paths using lodash _.set()
    if (typeof o[1] === 'number' || o[1]) {
      _.set(newObj, o[0], o[1]);
    }
  });
  return newObj;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

[ElasticObject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elastic-object) is a wrapper for objects that adds array methods to objects. I would use that and than its `filter` method.

Comment: That's a fresh stew, @Dieter!!! :)
Unfortunately I am on CJS...

Comment: I did take it for a spin, but I honestly donät see how it could solve my issue and `filter` I already have in vanilla node.js and "dotted" path in lodash `get/set`. I am downvoting as you haven't really understood my problem and seem to mostly want to promote your own package...

Comment: Also, next time, a code sample that is using your package would be helpful to prove that it is actually solving the problem! Thanks for taking the time though!